# How to load extension for SQLite (SQLite + Entity Framework Core)

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core, .net-8.0, system.data.sqlite

I am using SQLite with Entity Framework Core in my .NET project. But I want to add some extensions for SQLite. How to correctly load SQLite extension? Nuget package does not exists, only .dll SQLite extension.

I found this article [Loading SQLite Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/extensions), but there using `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection`, and I don't understand, how I may config `DbContext` service in `Startup` class or something else.

Comment: Check this [comment](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/30522#issuecomment-1485726842), but from my perspective it is better to create interceptor [IDbConnectionInterceptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.diagnostics.idbconnectioninterceptor?view=efcore-8.0) instead of using single connection.

Answer (score 2):

I create `IDbConnectionInterceptor`

```
public class SQLiteExtensionInterceptor : IDbConnectionInterceptor
{
    public DbConnection ConnectionCreated(ConnectionCreatedEventData eventData,
        DbConnection result)
    {
        var sqliteConnection = (SqliteConnection)result;
        sqliteConnection.EnableExtensions();
        sqliteConnection.LoadExtension(@"path to extension");
        return sqliteConnection;
    }
}
```

and in `Startup.cs` `ConfigureServices()` add DB service

```
services.AddDbContext<YourDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlite("connectionString");
    options.AddInterceptors(new SQLiteExtensionInterceptor());
});
```

Thanks for Svyatoslav Danyliv.